# PHP 5.4 Built in Server, Fix file not found error

Tags: php, auraphp

I am using PHP 5.4 RC5, and starting the server via terminal

```
php -S localhost:8000
```

Currently using [Aura.Router](https://github.com/auraphp/Aura.Router/) , and at the root I have index.php file with code

```
<?php
$map = require '/Aura.Router/scripts/instance.php';

$map->add('home', '/');

$map->add(null, '/{:controller}/{:action}/{:id}');

$map->add('read', '/blog/read/{:id}{:format}', [
    'params' => [
        'id' => '(\d+)',
        'format' => '(\.json|\.html)?',
    ],
    'values' => [
        'controller' => 'blog',
        'action' => 'read',
        'format' => '.html',
    ]
]);

$path = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);

$route = $map->match($path, $_SERVER);
if (! $route) {
    // no route object was returned
    echo "No application route was found for that URI path.";
    exit;
}
echo " Controller : " . $route->values['controller'];
echo " Action : " . $route->values['action'];
echo " Format : " . $route->values['format'];
```

A request for `http://localhost:8000/blog/read/1` works as expected.

But when a dot json or dot html like `http://localhost:8000/blog/read/1.json` , `http://localhost:8000/blog/read/1.html` request comes, the php throws

```
Not Found
The requested resource /blog/read/1.json was not found on this server.
```

As I am running the server with the built in php server, where can I fix not to throw the html and json file not found error ?

Or do I want to go and install apache and enable mod rewrite and stuffs ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are trying to make use of a router script for the PHP built-in webserver without specifying it:

```
php -S localhost:8000
```

Instead add your router script:

```
php -S localhost:8000 router.php
```

A router script should either handle the request if a request matches, or it should return `FALSE` in case it want's the standard routing to apply. Compare [Built-in web server<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php).

I have no clue if *Aura.Router* offers support for the *built-in web server* out-of-the-box or if it requires you to write an adapter for it. Like you would need to configure your webserver for that router library, you need to configure the built-in web server, too. That's the `router.php` script in the example above.

Comment: You are right . `php -S localhost:8000 router.php` will work :) .

Answer (score 3):

you can specify the document root by passing the -t option like so:

```
php -S localhost:8888 -t c:\xampp\htdocs
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I'm not familiar with Aura.Router. However, I would use whatever is going on the production server. You might find some unexpected errors when you go live with the project if you do not sync the same program versions on your test and production servers.